# hovered state on mobile applications in actionscript doesnt work

Tags: actionscript

In my Code, actually the fontsize should change, if its hovered but it doesnt. Why not?
Because if i hover the the Label, the fontsize should switch to 20. Does anyone know where the problem is? Normally you should expect the font to be resized after its hovered, but it doesnt resize.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160">
 <fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

    <s:ArrayList id="employeList">
        <fx:String>Mein Buch, was geht</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Der Graf von Monte Christo</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Hier steht das neu buche</fx:String>
        <fx:String>hmmm</fx:String>
    </s:ArrayList>


    <s:ArrayList id="testList">
        <fx:Object test="try" test2="this"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object test="out" test2="plz"></fx:Object>
    </s:ArrayList>
</fx:Declarations>



<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{(testList)}" >
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout>

        </s:VerticalLayout>
        </s:layout>

    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:states>
                    <s:State name="normal">

                    </s:State>

                    <s:State name="hovered"   >

                    </s:State>

                    <s:State name="selected"   >

                    </s:State>
                </s:states> 
                <s:BorderContainer>
                    <s:layout >
                <s:HorizontalLayout          
                    horizontalAlign="center" paddingBottom="80">

                        </s:HorizontalLayout>
                    </s:layout>
                    <s:Label text="{data.test}  {data.test2}" 

                                  fontSize.hovered="20" fontSize.selected="30">

                    </s:Label>

                    <s:CheckBox>

                    </s:CheckBox>

                </s:BorderContainer>

            </s:ItemRenderer>

        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:DataGroup>
 </s:Application>
```

Comment: I don't think mobile devices have a "hovered" state as such.  You would probably rather use your equivalent of MOUSE_DOWN

Comment: If you use mouse down, would you use mouse up to deselect? What if you havent focused the specific label, you went down on with you mouse?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you write

<s:Label
       text="{data.test} {data.test2}" 
       fontSize.hovered="20" fontSize.selected="30">

which specifies what the font is for the **hovered** and **select** state, however you do not specify what the font is for the **normal** state.

Since it is not specified in the above code what the font is for the normal state, there *may* not be an obvious difference between the font in the normal state vs. the font in the hovered state.

I suggest you start by adding another parameter:

```
  fontSize="10"
```

That will apply when the other fontSize.*state* parameters do not apply.